# Where can I find the auto rig pro?

Tags: auto-rig-pro

just a new guy in the Blender, I installed auto rig pro and enabled it, but I can't find it , then I opened the Add-ons the Location shows: **3Dview > properties > rig main properties**.

I followed the information to search it and still can't find it in the 3Dview. I can`t even find the rig main properties where can I find the auto rig pro?
[image]

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjA1s.png)
[image]

Comment: Auto Rig Pro is a paid addon and not shipped with Blender. Following thje first link on your favorite search engine should lead you to a reseller. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your addon is installed, but it is not active yet... You need to click here to activate it:

[image]

After this it should be where it is supposed to be

Comment: thanks for responding，I tried  your suggestion to activate it, but it didn`t show up,Whatever I activate it or not nothing happen in the 3Dview or properties, still can`t figure out what is going on. Still appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Really? Are you sure it is supposed to be there? I don't know that addon and I cannot use it as it is paid, in this case I can only recommend to ask them and write to support of this addon

Comment: Maybe It`s my blender`s problem or I installed it in a wrong way,I`ll try to figure out what happen to my blender and  the addon.

Comment: the whole system for addons is pretty straightforward, just press install, select zip, and check the unchecked box next to addon name, that's all and nothing else to do. Is there no error at the bottom of the Blender window? Are you using correct version of Blender and addon?